# How to get source code from runtime version?

Tags: java, arrays, winapi, boolean, bluej

Hi ive a File that has been given to me but it gives no source code its just a runtime version of the project is there anyway in which i can get the source code without having to rewrite it im using Bluej to do this 
Thanks

Comment: If it is a jar file then you may use java decompiler.

Comment: im not exactly a genius with this now but i think its a rar file sorry if that dosent help

Answer (score 0):

User JAVA DE-COMPILER, you can get it from [here](http://jd.benow.ca/).

Answer (score 0):

See [JD Project](http://jd.benow.ca/) for a decompiler that will do the job.